# sort list by reverse highest, number, than alphabetically

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting

I have a python list which contains the following data:

```
[('c',3),('a',1),('d',1),('b',5)]
```

I would like to order it so that first it is ordered by highest number:

```
[('b',5),('c',3),('d',1),('a',1)]
```

And then order it alphabetically

```
[('b',5),('c',3),('a',1),('d',1)]
```

Can I do this using one sort function?

Comment: Represent list in this way - `[('c',3),('a',1),('d',1),('b',5)]` else those values `c,a,...` will be treated as variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = [("c",3),("a",1),("d",1),("b",5)]
sorted(s, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
# gives [('b', 5), ('c', 3), ('a', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

Comment: Perfect and if you want to do it in-place, use `s.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))`